# Select multiple data from 2 tables and button will disable after clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table... how to select all data from table pelajar. at the same time.. after + button is clicked.. it will disable...

my if else like this :

```
if ((penyertaan.no_matrik==pelajar.no_matrik)&&(penyertaan.status_mohon ='wajib'))
{
    echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"tambah_disable\" id=\"tambah_disable\" value=\"+\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>";
}
```

I've included below the table, attributes and data.

table 1 : pelajar
attributes : nama, no_matrik, kod_kursus, tahun
data :  nama = NADIA, no_matrik = 1, kod_kursus = BIT, tahun = 1

table 2 : penyertaan
attributes :no_matrik, status_mohon
data :  no_matrik = 1, status_mohon = wajib

Comment: There is a lot on both of these available: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+from+two+tables and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+button+after+clicked

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to disable the button after someone clicks it once. You'll have to use javascript for that.

```
document.getElementById("button_id").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can disable the button like this:

```
$('#tambah_disable').attr("disabled", true);
```